# Log4j2 security issue

Tags: log4j2, maven-plugin

Currently , I am using apachie.logging.log4j. artifact is log4j-slf4j-impl . Version 2.12.0.

My question is that log4j-slf4j-impl is also affected by this recent security vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this version is vulnerable.
It has a transitive runtime dependency to `log4j-core` in version 2.12.0. which contains the vulnerability.

So you should update `log4j-slf4j-impl` to Version [2.15.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.15.0) containing the fix as fast as possible.

Comment: Also, if for some reason you cannot immediately upgrade, a workaround is to set `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` to true, like  `java -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: what is myapp.jar in this case?